# Angled background (triangle) button on hover

Tags: html, css

I have the following css/html which puts a 'back to top' button on the bottom right corner of the window. When hovered over, the background animates up behind it.

The code works fine, but I am trying to do it with a triangle instead. It would be in the bottom right, and the background would animate up, but on an angle instead of straight up.

```css
#top-btn {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 900;
}

#top-btn a,
#top-btn-BG {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#top-btn a {
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 34px 35px;
  color: #707070;
  bottom: 0;
}

#top-btn-BG {
  z-index: 950;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: #333;
  bottom: -75px;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
  -ms-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
  transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
}

#top-btn a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#top-btn a:hover+#top-btn-BG {
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-btn" class="flex">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="scrolltop();"> button </a>
  <div id="top-btn-BG"></div>
</div>
```

I want the bottom-right corner triangle to look like this when hovered over

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just use a simple css triangle generator.
http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/

Comment: I have tried that, the problem is that the hover effect I'm looking for (animating up similar to my code) doesn't seem to work for me using that technique

Answer (score 0):

You can use some `border` properties for geometric shapes.

Here is a fiddle with an exemple :

https://jsfiddle.net/gsep39po/

Comment: That's close, but the triangle i'm looking for is bottom right. The 'point' of the triangle pointing into the corner. So the hover effect would go from bottom-right to top-left direction

Comment: Try to use `rotation` properties if you want to turn your triangle in the right direction.

Comment: Which is where i run into issues to get the hover effect to work when the triangle is rotated

Answer (score 0):

You could do that using `pseudo selector ::before` to style new triangle at top,

```
#top-btn-BG:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 40px solid #333;
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #333;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: -4px;
}
```

```css
#top-btn {
  position: fixed;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 900;
}

#top-btn a,
#top-btn-BG {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#top-btn a {
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 34px 35px;
  color: #707070;
  bottom: 0;
}

#top-btn-BG {
  z-index: 950;
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: #333;
  bottom: -130px;
  -webkit-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
  -moz-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
  -ms-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
  -o-transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
  transition: bottom 0.35s ease;
  right: 0px;
}

#top-btn-BG:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border: 40px solid #333;
  border-top: 40px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 40px solid #333;
  border-left: 40px solid transparent;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
  bottom: 100%;
  right: -4px;
}

#top-btn a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}

#top-btn a:hover + #top-btn-BG {
  bottom: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="top-btn" class="flex">
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="scrolltop();"> button </a>

  <div id="top-btn-BG"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Right idea but I think I'm mis-communicating the triangle I am looking for. I will update my question with imagery

Comment: @user3550879 Still not clear, how you are expecting it to grow, but you could rotate and translate pseudo selector to get output same as in your provided image.

Comment: right, I want the bottom of the triagle to grow. So it looks like it's coming from the bottom-right. It doesn't even have to be a triangle if a rotated rectabgle could be off screen and grow